# Run android app on debian without emulator

Tags: debian, android

I'm trying to install a few android games on Debian.
I've tried Bluestacks (via WINE), Genymotion, AndroVM, Android-x86 and I still can't get these few games (Samurai Siege, and Clash of the Clans).

Is there any other way?

Comment: coteyr is correct. Because they are different platforms, the only way you'll be able to run the applications is with the Java JDK emulator or another android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can not. They are different hardware platforms. Your phone is probably arm based and your desktop is probably x86 based.